# Python2: the meaning of '!../'

Tags: python-2.7, sh, caffe

Hi I am studying caffe by this tutorial (http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/tutorial/examples/00-caffe-intro.ipynb)

I don't know the meaning of '!../' in the code like the following code:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'):
    print 'CaffeNet found.'
else:
    print 'Downloading pre-trained CaffeNet model...'
    !../scripts/download_model_binary.py ../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet

# load ImageNet labels (for understanding the output)
labels_file = 'synset_words.txt'
if not os.path.exists(labels_file):
    print 'begin'
    !../home2/challege98/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh
    print 'finish'
labels = np.loadtxt(labels_file, str, delimiter='\t')
```

Could you explain it in detail, when I run the code, there is error that:

```
Downloading pre-trained CaffeNet model...
/bin/sh: 1: ../scripts/download_model_binary.py: not found
begin
/bin/sh: 1: ../home2/challege98/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh: not found
finish
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8534d29d47f5> in <module>()
     12     get_ipython().system(u'../home2/challege98/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh')
     13     print 'finish'
---> 14 labels = np.loadtxt(labels_file, str, delimiter='\t')
     15 
     16 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
    856                 fh = iter(bz2.BZ2File(fname))
    857             elif sys.version_info[0] == 2:
--> 858                 fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
    859             else:
    860                 fh = iter(open(fname))

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'synset_words.txt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclamation point is to run a shell command. See [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/12/using-shell-commands-effectively-ipython/).

The error you are seeing is because the file `synset_words.txt` does not exist and is not being created because it cannot find the script to create it. Check this path is correct: `../home2/challege98/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh`